# Pivot table from dataframe column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I have the following data in Python data frame:

| Week | Workstation | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | DD |
| 1 | A | DD |
| 1 | B | DD |
| 1 | C | FF |

I want to create a pivot table that returns the distinct values of workstation and reason per week in python. Expected output as below:

| Week | Distinct_Workstation | Distinct_Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |

I tried this:

```py
df.pivot_table(index='Week', values=['Workstation', 'Reason'], aggfunc='nunique')
```

However that doesn't give me the right values.

Comment: And what did you try? What was the result? You didn't post any attempt.

Comment: updated post with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `Week` and find [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) for other columns:

```
df.groupby('Week', as_index=False).nunique()
```

---

```
   Week  Workstation  Reason
0     1            3       2
```

Comment: It's better to use `df.groupby('Week', as_index=False).nunique()`

Answer (score 1):

```
# To find number of distinct categories in Workstation and Reason
dictAgg = {'Workstation':[('nunique', 'nunique')],
'Reason':[('nunique', 'nunique')]}

df.groupby('Week', as_index=False).agg(dictAgg)
```